# Why doesn't Apache 2.4 respect VirtualHosts?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

I have migrated from Raring to Saucy on my web server, and with it, upgraded Apache from 2.2.x to 2.4.x.

Apache now seems not to be aware of the sites-enabled directory or its content. Every host is served up with the 000-default.conf. An example of a VirtualHost is `006-cjshayward`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cjshayward.com
    ServerAdmin CJSHayward@PObox.com

    DocumentRoot /home/jonathan/cjshayward/public_html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/author.cjshayward.error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.cjshayward.com
    ServerAlias author.cjshayward.com cjsh.name www.cjsh.name cjsh.info www.cjsh.info
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cjshayward.com$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

What else do I need to do to register as having a VirtualHost with its own parent directory?

Comment: Is the `Include` line for `sites-enabled` still present in `apache2.conf`?  That's what's responsible for loading the contents of those files.

Comment: Always post the result of httpd -S (or, for Debuntu systems, apache2ctl -S) when discussing vhost problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache 2.2's apache2.conf had this directive: `Include sites-enabled/*`

Apache 2.4's apache2.conf has switched to using this directive: `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`

Most likely the files in your `sites-enabled` directory do not end in `.conf`

Answer (score 1):

As Shane mentions you need to make sure httpd.conf is including files from your sites-enabled folder.

Further, most Debian based distributions will include all files in the sites-enabled folder, while, last I checked the Redhat "equivalent" will only include files with a .conf extension.

Either way, this needs to be present in your httpd.conf:

```
Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*
```